# Is it possible to make an SSRS report export to PDF when run?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to find a way to get an SSRS report, when opened, export the results directly to a PDF file and have some control over the name of the file saved on the server. Ideally, without displaying anything to the user opening the web page the SSRS report is on.

The scenario is thus:
Working within an off the shelf web site content management system. I can 'load' an .RDL file into this system and have it display on a web page. This system supports SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014 versions of .RDL only.
I have the SSRS report (created in VS 2015, with target version set to SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014) working and ready to go. It is being used under the same system so I know the report runs/renders OK.

Primary Use case is to 'capture' customer data in the format of this report before the customer makes any changes so we have a complete record of what the data was before any changes were made. This report is meant to replace a paper document with a very specific format.

Server running SQL 2014 has Reporting Services installed. Never used it so don't know if it will help with this.

Long preamble to the fundamental question. Is it possible to make an SSRS report 'self export' as PDF and programatically set the filename of the PDF file?

Any and all suggestions/ideas are welcome.

Comment: Not directly in SSRS no. You would need to build your own web page, which accepts the needed parameters, and then does the "grunt work" in the back ground. How you implement that is a *completely* different question to what is being asked here.

Comment: You can open a report (with parameters if required) and render it directly to PDF format with something like `http://myServer/ReportServer?/ReportName&rs:Format=PDF ` .  See here for more details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access?view=sql-server-ver15 . HOWEVER, you cannot control the filename, as @Larnu stated, you would need to write something to control that. There are plenty of similar questions on SO that you might find useful.

Comment: You can run SSRS reports via [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) and specify the render format as part of the URL.

Comment: This did get to be more complicated than I had hoped, but with suggestions above I have enough to go on.
Found this page https://www.adelomar.com/posts/2019/07/export_ssrs_report_into_pdf_format_from_asp.net_application/ with a code sample that looks like it will work.
Thanks all for you suggestions.